# Where can I download FireFox v.21?

Tags: firefox

I installed the latest version - 22 and it's very unstable on my machine. Crashed a few times a day and some of the games (Ikariam) has shakey graphics. Also, most of the web pages are "zoomed up" so everything seems a bit unpleasant.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I also tried deactivating plugins and other stuff. To no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download any Firefox release from https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/.